# Java Pattern match from List

Tags: java, regex

I have a list that contains below pattern:

```
List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
listStrings.add("Product-typeA"); 
listStrings.add("Product-typeA-2");
listStrings.add("Product-typeA-3");
listStrings.add("Product-typeA-5");
listStrings.add("Product-typeB");
listStrings.add("Product-typeB-2");
listStrings.add("Product-typeC");
listStrings.add("Product-typeC-2");
listStrings.add("Product-typeC-3");
System.out.println(listStrings);
```

How can I get the search for Specific product type using pattern (or any better way) and get the Max number of that product type and add it to the list. for example : if I search for the max value of `Product-typeA` it should return `Product-typeA-6` and add it to the list.

Comment: You should really consider using a different data structure instead of a list of "concatenated string data". You can use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to store the same information with *faster* lookups and waste *much less* space.

Comment: Why should it return `Product-typeA-6`, when the max value for any element that starts with `Product-typeA` is `Product-typeA-5` (5, not 6)? This of course assumes that you want to search items *starting with* `Product-typeA`, which is not clear from the question text.

Comment: I am sorry, I am looking for Next Max number for Product TypeA in the question which is 6.

Answer (score 1):

You could stream the list, extract the index, find the largest one and add one:

```
private static void addNext(List<String> list, String prefix) {
    int nextIndex =
            list.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.startsWith(prefix + "-"))
                .map(s -> s.replace(prefix + "-", ""))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().orElse(0);
    list.add(prefix + "-"  + nextIndex);
}
```